# Warning Invalid Argument for foreach()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, foreach

Ok, I have recently purchased a wordpress plugin called WPArcade but, I've been having some issues. In particular I can not get my games to feed like their suppose to. When I attempt to feed games from say, Kongregate, it says 0 games found but also gives me this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\wp\wp-content\plugins\wparcade-plugin\feeds\kongregate\kongregate.php on line 113

I am testing the site on a local server which is why it is in the C Drive.

Kongregates feed: http://www.kongregate.com/games_for_your_site.xml

This is occurring with every publisher in the plugin except for one which doesn't throw me the warning.

Lines 113 through 155: Kongregate

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($get_kongregate_feed);

foreach($xml->game as $game) {  
    $id = intval($game->id);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($game->title);
    $check_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."wparcade_kongregate_games WHERE id = '$id'");
    $count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as newgames FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."wparcade_kongregate_games WHERE id = '$check_id'"),0);

    if($count !== '1') {
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($game->title);
        $slug = mysql_real_escape_string($game->title);
        $slug = wparcade_stringforslug($slug);
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string($game->category);
        $category = wparcade_strstr_before($category, " & ");
        if(!$category) $category = mysql_real_escape_string($game->category);
        $categories = mysql_real_escape_string($game->category);
        $categories = str_replace(' & ', ', ', $categories);
        if(!$categories) $categories = mysql_real_escape_string($game->category);
        $description = mysql_real_escape_string($game->description);
        $instructions = mysql_real_escape_string($game->instructions);
        $thumbnail_url = mysql_real_escape_string($game->thumbnail);
        $swf_url = mysql_real_escape_string($game->flash_file);
        $width = $game->width;
        $height = $game->height;
        $tags = strtolower($categories);
        $author = mysql_real_escape_string($game->developer_name);
        $wparcade_kongregate_feed_game_status = $options['kongregate_feed_game_status'];
        $status = $wparcade_kongregate_feed_game_status;
        $feedsinglecat_id = $options['kongregate_feed_single_cat'];
        $feedcategory = get_cat_name($feedsinglecat_id);
        if($feedsinglecat_id !== 'none') { 
            $categories = $feedcategory;
            $category = $feedcategory;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."wparcade_kongregate_games (id, name, slug, description, thumbnail_url, swf_url, width, height, author, categories, category, tags, instructions, status) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$slug', '$description', '$thumbnail_url', '$swf_url', '$width', '$height', '$author', '$categories', '$category', '$tags', '$instructions', '$status')";

        $list .= '<li class="wparcade_new_games""><strong>'.$name.'</strong></li>';
        $wpdb->query($sql);
        $inserted++;

    } else {
        $list .= '<li class="wparcade_old_games"><strong>'.$name.'</strong></li>';
    }
}
```

Just in case, this is the code from the only feed that is working:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($get_scirra_feed);

foreach($xml->game as $game) {  
    $id = intval($game->gameid);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($game->name);
    $count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as newgames FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."wparcade_scirra_games WHERE id = '$id'"),0);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($game->category);
    $slug = mysql_real_escape_string($game->name);
    $slug = wparcade_stringforslug($slug);
    $check_for = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."wparcade_scirra_games WHERE slug = '$slug'");

    if($count !== '1' && $category !== 'Example' && !$check_for) {
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($game->name);
        $slug = mysql_real_escape_string($game->name);
        $slug = wparcade_stringforslug($slug);
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string($game->category);
        $category = str_replace('Shooter', 'Shooting', $category);
        $category = str_replace('Defence', 'Defense', $category);
        $category = str_replace('Puzzle', 'Puzzles', $category);
        $category = str_replace('Rotary', 'Arcade, Rotary', $category);
        $categories = $category;
        $description = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($game->description));
        $instructions = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($game->instructions));
        $thumbnail_url = $game->images->small;
        $thumbnail_large_url = $game->images->medium;
        $screen1_url = $game->images->big;
        $embed_url = mysql_real_escape_string($game->embedurl);
        $embed_url = str_replace('http://', '//', $embed_url);
        $embed_url = str_replace('//', 'http://', $embed_url);
        $width = $game->width;
        $height = $game->height;
        $tags = strtolower($categories);
        $author = mysql_real_escape_string($game->author->username);
        $wparcade_scirra_feed_game_status = $options['scirra_feed_game_status'];
        $status = $wparcade_scirra_feed_game_status;
        $feedsinglecat_id = $options['scirra_feed_single_cat'];
        $feedcategory = get_cat_name($feedsinglecat_id);
        if($feedsinglecat_id !== 'none') { 
            $categories = $feedcategory;
            $category = $feedcategory;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."wparcade_scirra_games (id, name, slug, description, thumbnail_url, thumbnail_large_url, screen1_url, embed_url, width, height, author, categories, category, tags, instructions, status) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$slug', '$description','$thumbnail_url', '$thumbnail_large_url', '$screen1_url', '$embed_url', '$width', '$height', '$author', '$categories', '$category', '$tags', '$instructions', '$status')";

        $list .= '<li class="wparcade_new_games""><strong>'.$name.'</strong></li>';
        $wpdb->query($sql);
        $inserted++;

    } else {
        $list .= '<li class="wparcade_old_games"><strong>'.$name.'</strong></li>';
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

P.S. I asked on the plugin's support site but it's been almost a week with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that for Kongregate $xml->game isn't an iterateable object (like an array).  The simplest way to debug this is on line 113 try inserting something like:

```
print_r($xml->game); 
//or
print_r($xml);
```

Getting data visibility into what is and isn't working will probably help you better understand why this isn't working.  Good luck!

Comment: Not sure how to view that though. Inserting that into the program doesn't change anything when I run the feed. Now i just get an error on the next line with no printed info.

Comment: Just keep working backwards by printing out lines until you find the one that's causing you a problem.  I'd try printing $get_kongregate_feed if the rest isn't responding to be sure you're passing the right data in.  You need better visibility into what the actual values are.  If you pull this, go ahead and post the url you're trying to load in

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm not sure how to actually print the lines to find their value, as when I change the code it doesn't display the printed text when I run that particular part of the plugin.

Comment: Not sure how to help you with that specific plugin.  I'd recommend just putting a break after your print statement to have the script die.  Otherwise you'll need to chase down the output of the script in general.  Good luck!